# How did Sherlock write letters on Irene's mobile, when (usually) the lock-screen of phones accept digits not letters?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

How did Sherlock write letters on Irene's mobile in *A Scandal in Belgravia*, when (usually) the code for a lock screen of a phone contains 4 digits not letters?

He was trying numbers all through the episode, that means that the keys that are available are only numbers, so how could he write the word 'SHER'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He was trying numbers all the episode, that means that the keys that are available are only numbers

**It means no such thing and isn't true anyway**

He tried both random numbers AND letters previously.

[image]

Clearly the input accepted both numbers and letters.

In fact a 4 digit number is *significantly* less secure than a random **4 letter &/or 10 digit** code which given Irene's dependency on the phone's security makes sense.

It's probably not a *stock* passcode app, but a high security version.

Comment: It probably is a 'made for TV' passcode screen, but an iPhone can use [at least] a 20-char alphanumeric passcode rather than the stock 6-digit.

Comment: @Tetsujin it shouldn't be the iphone we see generally. could be custom made, could be not an iphone etc etc\